# Apply function to create mean for filtered columns across multiple columns r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with likert scoring across multiple aspects of a course (about 40 columns of likert scores like the two in the sample data below).

Not all rows contain valid scores. Valid scores are 1:5. Invalid scores are allocated 96:99 or are simply missing.

I would like to create an average score for each individual ID for each of the satisfaction columns that:

1) filters for invalid scores,

2) creates a mean of the valid scores for each id .

3) places the mean satisfaction score for each id in a new column labelled [column.name].mean as in Skill.satisfaction.mean below

I have included a sample data frame and the transformation of the data frame that I would like on a single row below.

```
####sample score vector
possible.scores <-c(1:5, 96,97, 99,"")

####data frame
ratings <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1:7, each =2), 8:10), Degree = c(rep("Double", times = 14), rep("Single", times = 3)),
                      Skill.satisfaction = sample(possible.scores, size = 17, replace = TRUE), 
                      Social.satisfaction = sample(possible.scores, size = 17, replace = TRUE)
                      )

####transformation applied over one of the satisfaction scales
ratings<- ratings %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!Skill.satisfaction %in% c(96:99), Skill.satisfaction!="") %>%
  mutate(Skill.satisfaction.mean = mean(as.numeric(Skill.satisfaction), na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
ratings %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% 
        #Change satisfaction columns from factor into numeric
        mutate_at(vars(-ID,-Degree), list(~as.numeric(as.character(.)))) %>%
        #Get mean for values in 1:5 
        mutate_at(vars(-ID,-Degree), list(mean=~mean(.[. %in% 1:5], na.rm = T)))

# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Degree Skill.satisfaction Social.satisfaction Skill.satisfaction_mean Social.satisfaction_mean
  <int> <fct>               <dbl>               <dbl>                   <dbl>                    <dbl>
1     1 Double                 96                  99                       2                      NaN
2     1 Double                  2                  97                       2                      NaN
3     2 Double                  1                  97                       1                      NaN
4     2 Double                 97                  NA                       1                      NaN
5     3 Double                 96                  96                     NaN                        3
6     3 Double                 99                   3                     NaN                        3
```