# How to get number of values >= x across multiple columns

Tags: r, sum

I'm trying to count the number of times a value is greater than "x" across all my columns. There have been lots of examples that show this using the column names, but my column names are long and I'm trying to use the column numbers. Essentially I want sum of: the number of times each column has a value greater than 5 for each month. Here is a sample dataframe

```
# Create a, b, c, d variables
a <- c("06-25-20 08:00:00 AM","06-25-20 08:15:00 AM",
       "06-25-20 08:30:00 AM","06-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "09-25-20 08:45:00 AM","09-25-20 08:45:00 AM")
b <- c(4,5,8, "NA", 4,5,"NA",7,7,6)
c <- c(6,10,8, "NA", 8,5,"NA",8,7,2)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df$a = as.POSIXlt(df$a, format="%m-%d-%y%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')
```

Here is some sample code

```
Proportion_over_five = df %>% pivot_longer(-c(a)) %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(a), year = lubridate::year(a)) %>% 
  group_by(month, year, name) %>%
  summarise(count = sum(df[,2:3]>5))
```

When I use that code it gives me the wrong answers. I think it says 13 times for each column and each month.

I've also tried this code

```
Proportion_over_five = df %>% pivot_longer(-c(a)) %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(a), year = lubridate::year(a)) %>% 
  group_by(month, year, name) %>%
apply(X=df,2,FUN=function(x) length(which(df[,2:3] >= 20)))
```

and I get the error message

```
Error in `-.POSIXt`(left) : unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

so with this sample data frame the result should look like

```
month  year  a  b
06     2020  2  3
07     2020  1  2
08     2020  1  1
09     2020  2  1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to create mean for filtered columns across multiple columns r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743043/apply-function-to-create-mean-for-filtered-columns-across-multiple-columns-r)

Comment: Use `across` in lieu of `mutate_at` in the linked question? Otherwise, could you add what your expected output should look like (for a TLDR)?

Comment: in the link I can't see a place to indicate ">=5"

Comment: what are cols `a` & `b` in desired output??

Comment: columns ```a``` and ```b``` indicate the total number of times the value was >=5 in the original dataframe

Comment: you mean actually `b` and `c`?? right?

Comment: yes sorry, ```b``` and ```c```, not ```a``` and  ```b```

Comment: @AnilGoyal it looks like the code is evaluating a little strange with the ```NA``` in the dataframe. It's calculating some as >5, and in my original dataframe if there are ```NA```'s in the first couple rows of the month then the sum shows as ```NA```

Comment: Use na.rm = T inside sum()

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(a), year = lubridate::year(a)) %>% 
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = 2:3, ~ sum(. > 5)), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  month  year     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     6  2020     2     3
2     7  2020     0     1
3     8  2020     2     2
4     9  2020     2     1
```

Comment: yes but is there a way to do this without having to concatenate the column names, and instead use the column numbers? the column names I have in my original dataframe are long

Comment: yes, see edit. Just use `2:3` in `.cols` arg